# What is the best way to check for matching sets of rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was watching this video yesterday on how unlikely it is to shuffle a deck of cards the same way twice:

https://youtu.be/czSdEhtXwm4?t=300

And I thought to myself "My SAN adminsitrator still has some hair left."

So I built a quick deck of cards:

```
        declare @card int
        create table deck (card int)

        set @card = 1
        while @card <= 52
        begin
        insert into deck (card)
        values (@card)
        set @card += 1
        end
```

Shuffled them up:

```
        declare @shuffleID bigint
        create table shuffles (shuffleID bigint, position int, card int)

        select @shuffleID = isnull(max(shuffleid),0)+ 1 from shuffles

        while @shuffleID <= 10000

        begin

        insert into shuffles (shuffleID, position, card)
        select @shuffleID, rank() over (order by newid()), card from deck
        order by newid()

        set @shuffleID += 1

        end
```

Then saw how closely I could match them:

```
        select s1.shuffleID, s2.shuffleID, count(1) as match_count from shuffles s1
        inner join shuffles s2 on s1.position = s2.position and s1.card = s2.card 
            and s1.shuffleID != s2.shuffleID
        group by  s1.shuffleID, s2.shuffleID
        order by count(1) desc
```

The whole script looks like this:

```
        if object_id('dbo.deck') is not null begin drop table deck end
        if object_id('dbo.shuffles') is not null begin drop table shuffles end

        create table deck (card int)
        create table shuffles (shuffleID bigint, position int, card int)
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [huehuehue]
        ON [dbo].[shuffles] ([position],[card])
        INCLUDE ([shuffleID])

        declare @card int,
        @shuffleID bigint,
        @sql int
        set @card = 1
        while @card <= 52
        begin
        insert into deck (card)
        values (@card)
        set @card += 1
        end

        select @shuffleID = isnull(max(shuffleid),0)+ 1 from shuffles

        while @shuffleID <= 1000

        begin

        insert into shuffles (shuffleID, position, card)
        select @shuffleID, rank() over (order by newid()), card from deck
        order by newid()

        set @shuffleID += 1

        end

        select s1.shuffleID, s2.shuffleID, count(1) as match_count from shuffles s1
        inner join shuffles s2 on s1.position = s2.position and s1.card = s2.card 
            and s1.shuffleID != s2.shuffleID
        group by  s1.shuffleID, s2.shuffleID
        order by count(1) desc
```

The highest match I've got out of 1,000 shuffles is 8.

**Question:** What would be the fastest way to shuffle a deck of cards the same way twice?

Comment: Is this question limited to SQL Server 2008 R2, given that it's more of an arbitrary exercise?

Comment: @LowlyDBA nope! Have at it! (The plain SQL tag is not allowed =[ )

Comment: In other words, you're asking what is the probability of `NEWID()` generating a monotonic sequence of 52 values.

Comment: @mustaccio the way i've done it, yea, but I suspect there are some much faster ways to do it.

Comment: I wonder if most variants of this problem paired with in memory tables makes the approach more or less moot.

Comment: @LowlyDBA kind of, but the problem I'm running into is that it will always fill TempDB before it finds a perfect match. It would even fill any concievable SAN before you found a match, if you stored every value, so I'm thinking the optimal way to do it is to store a few TB of shuffles, then keep generating them one at a time and checking them against the table.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/2217/

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to check for matching sets of rows?

Generally, inner join on a key

> Probability of of the shuffling being the exact same?

[A big number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=52%21&lk=4) as [described in a few places](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-chance-of-shuffling-the-same-deck-of-cards-and-getting-the-same-order-of-cards-twice)

1 in 806,581,751,709,438,785,716,606,368,564,037,669,752,895,054,408,832,778,240,000,000,000

> What would be the fastest way to shuffle a deck of cards the same way
>   twice?

One way would be to just use a single table. I use a tally table for the initial insert to speed that up, and also use two CTE's for the shuffle. Is it the *fastest*? Not sure, but it's pretty quick!

```
drop table deck;
create table deck ([card] int primary key, pos int);

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E2
    )  

insert into deck (card,pos)
select   card = N
        ,pos = rank() over (order by newid())
from cteTally where N < 53;

;with shuffle1 as(
select card 
       ,pos =rank() over (order by newid())
from deck),

shuffle2 as(
select card 
       ,pos =rank() over (order by newid())
from deck)

select s1.card, s1.pos as s1, s2.pos as s2
from shuffle1 s1 
inner join shuffle2 s2 on s1.card = s2.card
where s1.pos = s2.pos
```

Takes about 4 milliseconds on my machine for the initial and follow on shuffles, on average.

**STATISTICS TIME FOR ENTIRE SCRIPT**

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 4 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(52 row(s) affected)
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 4 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

[image: Totals]

Comment: I've never seen this style before, but I kind of like it.